# PHP - Auto updating stage messages

Tags: php

I'm doing an in-depth PHP script that is broke up into several different stages. I have seen on some web applications, for example IP Board, display a message each time a stage has been completed. For Example..

```
Loading Plugins
Plugins loaded, configuring..
Adding Cache..
```

Each message obviously doesn't display until that stage has completed. Hopefully this makes sense. I presume it's done with some JS.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use jQuery / Ajax.